# Adaptive card in WPF throws error 'Value cannot be null parameter name:Key'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-core-3.1, adaptive-cards

I am trying to render Adaptive card in one of our WPF application. As I am very new to WPF, I thought to first implement and show basic adaptive card before moving to the actual requirement.
I have implemented the sample shown in [MS Link for rendering adaptive card using .Net WPF SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/net-wpf/render-a-card). I tried the same solution and done some necessary changes like below.

MainWindow.XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="MyFirstWPFDotNetApp.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="RenderAdaptiveCard" Margin="10" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="2" RenderingBias="Quality" Direction="-90"/>
            </Grid.Effect>
        </Grid>  
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind code:

```
using AdaptiveCards;
using AdaptiveCards.Rendering.Wpf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyFirstWPFApp
{
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAdaptiveCard();
        }

        private void LoadAdaptiveCard()
        {
            // Create a card renderer
            AdaptiveCardRenderer renderer = new AdaptiveCardRenderer();

            // If using the Xceed package, enable the enhanced input
            renderer.UseXceedElementRenderers();

            // For fun, check the schema version this renderer supports
            AdaptiveSchemaVersion schemaVersion = renderer.SupportedSchemaVersion;
            // Build a simple card
            // In the real world this would probably be provided as JSON
            AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0")
            {
                Body = { new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Hello World", Id="textWord" } }
            };

            try
            {
                // Render the card
                RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedCard = renderer.RenderCard(card);

                // Get the FrameworkElement

                // Add this to your app's UI somewhere
                RenderAdaptiveCard.Children.Clear();
                RenderAdaptiveCard.Children.Add(renderedCard.FrameworkElement);  // Added this line to render it into grid

                // (Optional) Check for any renderer warnings
                // This includes things like an unknown element type found in the card
                // Or the card exceeded the maximum number of supported actions, etc
                IList<AdaptiveWarning> warnings = renderedCard.Warnings;
            }
            catch (AdaptiveException ex)
            {
                // Failed rendering
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the same code in both .Net framework 4.7.1 and in .Net core 3.1 but in both the application I am getting error message

> Value can not be null. Parameter Name : Key

on the line `renderer.RenderCard(card);`. I am not able to understand is this example is half or did I need to add some other references or parameters? Tried to some research but not found any help on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this issue and saw your question unanswered, so I thought I still post here for anybody coming after us.

The issue here is that the AdaptiveCard object has an unassigned InternalId property, which gets used later in the AdaptiveCardRenderer.RenderAdaptiveCardWrapper method as an index to a dictionary for storage. This is what throws the very ambiguous exception, so just by instantiating your AdaptiveCard as the following will solve the issue:

```
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0")
{
  Body = { new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Hello World", Id = "textWord"} },
  InternalID = new AdaptiveInternalID()
}
```